# Read textfile with characters in legacy Fortran

Tags: fortran, character, fortran77

In a project wrapping legacy Fortran code in R a text-file is read by the subroutine "rfort". A working simplified version of the subroutine looks like follows:

```
  SUBROUTINE rfort()
  implicit none

  INTEGER I,IX,IY
  DIMENSION IX(10),IY(10)
  CHARACTER*6 NAME(10)

  OPEN(UNIT=8,FILE='TEST.DAT',STATUS='OLD')
  OPEN(UNIT=9,FILE='RESULT.DAT',STATUS='UNKNOWN')

  DO I=1,10
  READ(8,1020)IX(I),IY(I),NAME(I)
1020      FORMAT(8X,2I8,A6)
  WRITE(9,1030)IX(I),IY(I),NAME(I)      
1030      FORMAT(8X,2I8,A6)
  ENDDO
  CLOSE (8)
  CLOSE (9)
  END
```

The text-file ("TEST.DAT") consists of four variables: a row identifier (ignored), two integer variables ("IX", "IY") and one character variable ("NAME").

```
       1     395    1232 1084
       2     415    1242 1024
       3     433    1253 125
       4     409    1204 1256
       5     427    1217 105
       6     446    1226 1253
       7     489    1239 1254
       8     560    1255 1260a
       9     720    1270 1067
      10     726    1293 1078d
```

While the subroutine compiles fine (on MacOS 10.11.6, R 3.5.0) with

```
R CMD SHLIB rfort.f
```

and can also invoked in R with

```
dyn.load("rfort.so")
```

and runs without error with

```
.Fortran("rfort")
```

it strangely reads in only the integer columns as is tested by "RESULT.DAT". The character column is ignored, whatever I tried. The very same code works as expected as a stand-alone Fortran-programme (compiled with gfortran 6.1.0), so I suspect it has something to do with the formatting. However, I am at my wits' end, so any help is appreciated!

Answer (score 1):

I think the 8X in your READ format should be 4X. Let's look at the first input line (I have added column numbers):

```
         1         2
1234567890123456789012345
   1     395    1232 1084
```

The format is `8X,2I8,A6`. We skip columns 1-8 and start reading the first integer from columns 9-16, which is `b395bbbb` and the second from columns 17-24 `1232bb10`. As you can see, part of the character data is being read as the second integer. The default of BLANK='NULL' means that embedded blanks are ignored (I assume you are not using a FORTRAN 66 compiler!)

Why you say it seems to work with gfortran, I don't know. Nor do I know why the results should be different depending on how you invoke the subroutine.

Comment: I feel it's quite likely the `8X` would be correct: the first four columns of the input text data being swallowed by the markdown parser.  Especially given the indentation of the code and the [tag:fortran77] tag.

Comment: Thank you for your input, and sorry for the confusion! I also think that `8X` is correct.  "1" is headed by seven blanks, "10" by six and so on. The first blanks were indeed swallowed.

Comment: I actually agree with Steve, 8x should be 4x, in both read and write. Then the input and output are identically spaced, except the output doesn't have the row numbers. But if you use `*` in the read, as in my answer, then it doesn't matter.

Answer (score 0):

In your example, it appears you want the output file to consist of the final 3 columns from TEST.DAT, but the output is not what you expect to see. 
You have two choices: 1) change the spacing in TEST.DAT to match the format statements, or 2) change the format statements to match the spacing in TEST.DAT.

Let's look at your format statements. The 1020 format says to skip the first 8 columns, read 2 integer types from the next 16 columns (8 columns for each int), and then a character type from the next 6 columns. For example, line 10 from TEST.DAT is read as follows:

```
TEST.DAT (line 10) with spacing illustrated:
       |       |       |     |
123456781234567812345678123456
  10     726    1293 1078d
```

As you can see, the value '726' is read into IX(10), but '12393107' is read into IY(10), and '8d' is read into NAME(10). Awesome, right, but not what you expected! Then when the output is printed numbers are right-aligned by default, while characters are left-aligned by default, so the last two columns in RESULTS.DAT are printed without a blank space between them:

```
RESULTS.DAT (line 10) with spacing illustrated:
       |       |       |     |
123456781234567812345678123456
             726 12931078d
```

Here's my recommendation: change your read format so that it is much more forgiving and flexible. Simply replace the `1020` specifier to `*`, which means that each item on the line (comma or space-separated) forms a sequence that will be transferred into the corresponding variable in your I/O list. This is called the `list-directed` format specifier. Note that because the row number becomes part of the input list, you will need to define an integer `integer dummy_val` (at the top of the subroutine) which you can then ignore. Now read each line using:

```
read(8, *) dummy_val, IX(i), IY(i), NAME(i)
```

You can do the same thing for your write statment: `write(9,*), IX(i), IY(i), NAME(i)` which will use a reasonable default field width and guarantee that a blank space exists between each item in the I/O list. If you want more control over how the output is formatted, continue to use a format statement, but change it so that a certain number of spaces are guaranteed to be placed between each item:

```
write(9, "(4x,I8,I8,1x,A6)") IX(i), IY(i), NAME(i)
```

Comment: Thanks for the detailled answer! However, the spacing was mingled up by markdown. I have edited "TEST.DAT", so that it reflects the original version (with 8 spaces for the row counter). Still, your suggestion to make the formatting more forgiving does not work, at least on my system. R is crashing, with only the first line in "RESULT.DAT" written.

Comment: @Nils Crashing might be an R related thing? Runs fine with gfortran and ifort here. Are the write statements still placed in a do loop? And if that doesn't work, try the explicit format.

Comment: I now tried the explicit format with the read-format-string like `1020      FORMAT(8X,I8,I8,1X,A6)`. It appears that only the first character of the string is read, so with `1X` the NAME-column appears but only the first character (in this case "1"). With `2X` the second character is displayed, and so on. It is definitely a R-specific problem, but I still do not know how to solve it.